# Distinguish between simulation and HDL code generation in simulink

Tags: matlab, vhdl, simulink, hdl

I am building a model using Simulink / Matlab Embedded Coder which is then converted to VHDL through HDL Coder. It should behave slightly different in simulation versus HDL, in particular concerning debug-output.

Is there a programmatic way to distinguish which target is selected? This should preferably not need a manual switch such as "DEBUG = 1;" and ensure that disabled code or sub-models will not be synthesized at all. If the different "accelerator" modes could also be distinguished, that would be a plus.

**Update:**
Such a switch should come into effect *before* the HDL code is auto-generated, since I want to avoid to manually touch generated code.

**Solution:**
I found a solution that partially answers my question: [EnvironmentController](http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/simulink/slref/environmentcontroller.html) offers such a switch in Simulink. Maybe there's also an Embedded-Matlab-only way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have MATLAB code in your Simulink model you can use `coder.target` to identify the target. You can differentiate between "C" code generation and "HDL" code generation using this.

`coder.target("HDL")` would be true when you are generating HDL.

Doc for this is at http://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ref/coder.target.html